# Search old yoga text

Tags: vedas, ramayana, puranas, bhagavad-gita, bhagavata-purana

I am french. I am looking for an appropriate English translation of ancient Sanskrit texts on yoga, in which the Ashta-Siddhis are described and written word for word exactly as for the version below or about the same as the version Below.
Would you please kindness help me find this.

- version of the Ashta-Siddhis described in the ancient yoga texts:
  1.- Anima = ability to make one's PHYSICAL BODY small, even smaller than an atome.
  2.- Mahima = ability to make one's PHYSICAL BODY as big as one wishes.
  3.- Laghima = ability to make the PHYSICAL BODY as light as one wants.
  4.- Garima = ability to make the PHYSICAL BODY as heavy as one wishes.
  5.- Praapti = ability to acquire any material items in the world.
  6.- Prakaamya = ability to satisfy any wish one has in the mind.
  7.- Ishitva = ability to roll over anyone.
  8.- Vashitva = ability to control anyone's mind and make him work according to his wish.
  *(Internet source).

Thank you very much.